# Linux access memory traced process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, archlinux

I am writing a small tracing mechanism for academic purposes. This program tracks another process using ptrace and I need to compare different way to access its memory to retrieve information such as system call arguments.

Can you tell me where I can find a comprehensive list or just tell which different mechanisms exist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar project. You can try [Vmtrace](http://linux-mm.org/VmTrace) or [PageTrace](http://linux-mm.org/PageTrace)
they provide withe the pages accessed by each process